# Can't add modifed elements to Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have select of events from db. 
I need clone each element 30 times and set elem.shedule different dates (every day at current month -2013-04-01 .. 2013-04-30).

It is my code ('shedule' field is date):

```
daily_events = Events.All
repeated_events = []
for event in(daily_events)
  for day in(1..date.end_of_month.day)
    repeat_event = event
    repeat_event.shedule = Date.new(date.year, date.month, day)
    repeated_events << repeat_event
  end
end
```

But as results I have each elem 30 times everywhere with same last of month day date (2013-04-30)

How to fix it?

If I set `repeated_events+=repeat_event` instead of `repeated_events << repeat_event`
I have TypeError in EventsController#index
can't convert Event to Array (Event#to_ary gives NilClass)

I think it is because I clone just a reference to element, not contents of element. What is way to fix it?

Comment: the output you got show here,with saying how you want looks like to be? which would help in quick fix

Comment: If I set dr+=repeat_event instead of dr.push(repeat_event)
I have TypeError in EventsController#index

can't convert Event to Array (Event#to_ary gives NilClass)

Comment: I need have at new array 'dr' the same object but with different dates (2013-04-01 .. 2013-04-30). But I have 30 objects with same date (2013-04-30)

Comment: sorry to say you, your question is not clear,quickly update your post,with specific points.

Comment: What is specific points? I don't quite inderstand

Comment: Changed description a little bit

Comment: `repeat_event = event` does not copy an event, it just points the variable `repeat_event` to the existing object

Comment: So how I may copy object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I need deep copy and use Marshal module

So my solution is

```
repeat_event = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(every_day_event))
```

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

Each time through the inner loop, `repeat_event` is a reference to the same `event` object.  Your array ends up storing many references to that single object, so when you make an assignment to `repeat_event.shedule`, it affects them all.

Try using `dup` to make a copy, like so:

```
repeat_event = event.dup
```

Comment: I tried to do it but now get strange error Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"events", :id=>#<Event title: "Return All day from 2013-04-08", shedule: "2013-04-01", user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, repeat: "daily">}

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.